# Setting the Page-Title in .Net using C# from a Class

Tags: c#, .net, class, methods, page-title

Question,

How do i set the title of a page from a class.  Is it even possible?  I can and have set the page title from a page itself and a usercontrol.

Can I, How Do I do this via a class using C# .Net

Here is what im looking to do,
From the Aspx Page i want to call a function that passes in the string title, and have the class set the page title.

**SomePage.Aspx.CS**

```
page_onload()   {   setPageTitle(titleValue);   }
```

**SetPageTitleClass.CS**

```
public static void setPageTitle(string iTitle)   {   Page.title = iTitle;  }
```

> The problem is "Page.Title" is not available from the Class

Comment: @sia why not just set it directly in the SomePage.Aspx.cs? u are replacying Title = titleValue with setPageTitle(titleValue);, is there anything else that you want to achieve in there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First: why would you want to do that? --- give it back and let the page set it ... u can set it in a base class or master page.

If you still want to do it, is along the lines:

```
var page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
page.Title = "someTitle";
```

Comment: this was exactly what i was looking for, i just wanted to created a class that handles the title outside the page, just makes it easier to manage with all the dynamic pages.

THANKS SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass in a reference to the Page you want to set the title of to the c# class you are going to use.

Could you post more detail about what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to have the class expose a TitleChanged event, which the page can subscribe to.

In this way, you are not tightly coupling your solution and everything is kept nice and clean.

Comment: Isn't that putting the cart before the horse?

Answer (score -2):

Yes. You must get a hold of the Page object. In the Page and UserControls this is relatively easy.

```
Page.Title = "My Title";
```